# JavaFX 8 : Combobox with full screen popup

Tags: combobox, javafx, popup, fullscreen

I currently develop a javafx application designed for windows 8 tablet. I use the JMetro theme (a little customized) for the whole application.

I would like the combobox to behave like on Android, opening a full screen popup list.

I think the better and simpler solution would be to create a new skin and to plug it with -fx-skin css ? After that I "only" have to create my popup, react to click event, and setValue of the combobox. I looked at the source code of ComboBoxListViewSkin but I don't see what to change if I extend it...

I there a build-in solution to display a fullscreen combobox popup ?

Any help appreciated. Thank for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple, but not evident for a beginner.

```
public class TouchComboBoxListViewSkin<T> extends ComboBoxListViewSkin<T> {
   private ComboBox<T> comboBox;
   public TouchComboBoxListViewSkin(ComboBox<T> comboBox) {
        super(comboBox);
        this.comboBox = comboBox;
   }


   @Override
   public void show() {
        //TODO use the accessible protected popup to display the list of items 
   }
}
```

and a little of css to use this skin :

```
.combo-box {
    -fx-skin: "path.to.TouchComboBoxListViewSkin";
}
```

Feel free to comment is this is not the right method.